# Principal ideal in an integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integral-domain

Let $R$ be an integral domain. How to prove that these two conditions are equivalent:

1. $(d) = (x_1, ..., x_n)$
2. $d | x_1, ..., x_n$ and $\exists a_1, ..., a_n \in R, d = x_1a_1+...+x_na_n$

I know that $x | y \Leftrightarrow (x) \geq (y)$, but I find it difficult to complete the proof.

Comment: With the fact you gave, and the definition of $(x_1\,\ldots, x_n)$, the proposition proves itself. It’s hard to see where you are stuck until you tell us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$d\mid x_1,\ldots, x_n\!\iff (d)\supseteq (x_1),\ldots, (x_n)\!\iff (d)\color{#c00} \supseteq \sum_i\, (x_i) =: (x_1,\ldots, x_n)$

$\exists\ a_i\!:\,\ d\, =\, \sum_i a_i x_i\iff\, d\,\in\,  \sum_i\, (x_i)
\iff (d) \color{#c00}\subseteq \sum_i\, (x_i) $

Comment: Why $(d) \subseteq \sum_i\, (x_i) \Rightarrow d\,\in\, \sum_i\, (x_i)$?

Comment: @ACartash The inclusion means every element of $(d)$ is in the ideal sum,  including the element $d\in (d)\ \ $

Comment: So, $1 \in R$ is required?

Comment: @ACartash The usual convention is that integral domains are rings with $1$. But even if not the prinicipal ideal $(a)$ is always defined so that it contains $a.\ \ $

Answer (score 0):

$(1)$ implies $(2)$

$(d)=(x_1,...,x_n)$ implies that $x_i\in (d)$ and $x_i=a_id$.
$(d)\in (x_1,..,x_n)$ implies $d=a_1x_1+...+a_nx_n$.

$(2)$ implies $(1)$. Let $d$ divides $x_i$ implies that $x_i=a_id$ and $x_i\in (d)$ and $(x_1,...,x_n)\subset (d)$.

$d=a_1x_1+...+a_nx_n$ implies that $d\in (x_1,...,x_n)$ and  $(d)\subset (x_1,...,x_n)$.

Comment: I'm still struggling with (1)$\Rightarrow$(2).

If $1 \in R$, then $\forall x_i$ $\exists y \in (d)$, $y = x_1 \cdot 0 + ... + x_i \cdot 1 + ... + x_n \cdot 0$ and $(d) \ni d \cdot 1 = a_1x_1 + ... + a_nx_n $ for some $a_1, ..., a_n \in R$. What if $1 \notin R$?